# How do I know that an object is not colliding with another object without using OnCollisionExit in c# unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I tried using `OnCollisionExit`, but it doesn't detect the other object's box `collider 2D` being disabled (When I disable the other objects box collider 2D it doesn't detect it as stopping being collided). I need the other objects `collider` to be disabled because I'm using it as a range indicator for punching and I don't want it to interact with other objects(example: The player pushes away the enemy with his range indicator). Is there another method I could use?

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "PunchRange")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Fight>().PunchInRange = true;
    }

    if (collision.collider.tag == "KickRange")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Fight>().KickInRange = true;
    }
}
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "PunchRange")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Fight>().PunchInRange = false;
    }
    if (collision.collider.tag == "KickRange")
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Fight>().KickInRange = false;
    }
}
```

I want it to detect whenever it is not colliding with an object even when the object's box `collider 2D` is disabled.

Comment: You may want to look into layers for collision or trigger. It seems your issue is that you want the collider off so it does not interact with other objects. So either you need to have the collider checking for defined layers, or then make it trigger so it detects collision but does not resolve it (no bumping/stopping).

Comment: you could maybe use a [`Physics2D.OverlapBoxNonAlloc`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html) and check whether there were any changes in comparison to the last frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restructure your introduction as it is so convoluted idk what you exactly want.

To detect collision or its lack you have to use colliders(maybe put additional collider but as a trigger). However what I understood is that you want to use them as triggers. On Collider2D component there is value isTrigger that you can set. Setting it makes the collider still work but not phisically (other colliders can pass thru it). Set that on the collider and use:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit2D.html

That should work for you.